# Why does Safari automatically dismiss JavaScript alerts after a few seconds?

Tags: macos, safari, alert

My Safari (14.1.2, macOS 11.5.2) automatically dismisses [JavaScript alerts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) after a short period (ranging from ~0.2s to 5s). It does not matter if the website itself generates an alert or it's done via the browser console:

[image]
<sub>(trust me, I'm not using the keyboard or mouse meanwhile)</sub>

Other browsers (Firefox, Chrome) don't display this behaviour. What could be going on here? I have no extensions installed, and switching to private browsing does not make a difference. How can I disable this behaviour? (I know alerts are bad UX, but sometimes they're the easiest way to debug things...)

Additional information: for websites hosted on the `localhost` domain, the alert is *not* dismissed automatically.

Comment: When I tried the exact same thin shown in the GIF, my banner was persistent. Did you recently edit any defaults in terminal or preferences before this occurred? Did this occur when you upgraded from catalina? I’m using Big Sur 11.6 and safari 14.1.2

Comment: Also tried what's shown in the GIF (alerting from Safari debug console), while on this page, alerts stays up until dismissed.  Safari 14.1.2, macOS 11.6.

Comment: This is very weird and not the behavior for me either. What if you use a confirm() or prompt() instead of alert()?

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing it myself after upgrading to macOS 11.6 / Safari 15. I will keep you posted if the bug resurfaces.

Comment: @Josh it's happening again right now, and `confirm()` and `prompt()` exhibit the same behaviour. I can't remember having changed any defaults.

Comment: @Glorfindel and what is the return value if confirm or prompt?

Comment: @Josh `false` resp. `null`

Comment: I feel like this must be some kind of malware because Safari really shouldn’t be doing that… I’ll see if I can think of more troubleshooting steps